# Navigation using AngularJS $routeProvider + OnsenUI ons.navigator.pushpage()

Tags: angularjs, navigation, onsen-ui

I'm working on a AngularJS + OnsenUI project, and I'm having problems with the navigation.

Let's say that I have a module:

```
angular
    .module('app.home', ['ui.utils','ngRoute','ngAnimate'])
    .controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl)
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
           .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'path/to/home/template',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/test1', {
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
        controller: 'TestOneCtrl'
    })
    .when('/test2', {
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
        controller: 'TestTwoCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'path/to/home/template'
    });
```

});

In the HomeCtrl I'm supposed to (depending on the result of certain functions) navigate to either test1.html or test2.html. My problem is that I don't know how to link the routeProvider to the the ons.navigator.pushPage function.

This doesn't work:

```
var url = '/test1';
$scope.navigator.pushPage( url, { animation : 'slide' } );
```

This works:

```
var url = '/absolute/path/to/template';
$scope.navigator.pushPage( url, { animation : 'slide' } );
```

My question is what do I need to do so I don't have to write the absolute path to the template in the url variable? Apparently I'm missing out on something, but I can't figure out what.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the *path* used in *$routeProvider* is not the same type of that of *pageUrl* used in *navigator.pushPage()*.

```
$routeProvider.when(path, route);
```

and

```
navigator.pushPage(pageUrl, option);
```

*Path* is like the pattern or string of your app url found in the browser address bar. For example, *`"http://localhost:8000/app/index.html#/test1"`*. That's when you can refer to this in the *routeProvider* as *"/test1"*. However, in the *navigator.pushPage()*, you will need to specify exact url to the page just like how you set ur *templateUrl* inside *$routeProvider*. In other words, *pageUrl* = *route*.

That's just from my understanding though.